# Blade directive not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and trying to define a blade directive (in the `boot()` method of the service provider):

```
Blade::directive('hello', function () {
        return "Hello, World!";
});
```

But in my views, when i write `@hello` it shows `@hello` instead of "hello world" as it should.

I've done `artisan view:clear` (and `cache:clear` too) but still no result.

Comment: Have you added your service provider to config.php?

Comment: @Kyslik of course :)

Comment: Does the `boot()` method get called?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes i checked.

Comment: Put `dd(Blade::getCustomDirectives());` at the end of `boot()`. What does it say?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir array:1 [▼
  "hello" => Closure {#1117 ▶}
]

Comment: Can you check whether `storage/framework/views` is really empty after you call `artisan view:clear`?

Comment: Yes it's empty.

Comment: Then I guess you have to manually debug `BladeCompiler::compileStatement()` (after calling `artisan view:clear`).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir :( was hoping it didn't have to come to that... thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167104/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-goncalo-marrafa).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've found it!!! And now i feel like a dumb ass! :) My service provider was deferred and so, when the diretive was called it hadn't been defined yet since the service provider would only boot at a later stage... Thanks for you time!

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` fixed my issue.

Comment: ahhh. in my case i fixed it by php artisan view:clear + php artisan config:cache

Comment: @GonçaloMarrafa Soo how did you fixed it?

Comment: I tried everything and only this worked: remove manually the cached files from /bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 4):

You have to do the following

Include this lines

```
use App\TraitsFolder\BladeDirectives;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
```

and in your `AppServiceProvider` class, add this

use BladeDirectives;

If your laravel server is running, stop it and do the following

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

And then start the server again.

Answer (score 2):

I use Laravel 5.5 and it works for me.

Inside *boot()* function on ***AppServiceProvider.php*** file.

```
public function boot()
    {
        \Blade::directive('hello', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php echo 'Hello ' . {$expression}; ?>";
        });
    }
```

And inside view

```
@hello('Unai')
```

Result

```
Hello Unai
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still need to call it. Untested, but try:

```
<div>
    @hello()
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried like that also. Same results... The fact that the code apears in the view leads me to believe that the blade compiler is not recognizing it...

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is ok and @hello on the view is ok too.

Are you using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363460/blade-directive-not-working/57163529#comment85760429_49363460